# How get path to secondary external directory for Camera files

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a device with an SD card. Now I want to check that device has mounted an external SD card and can read files from the public DCIM folder. I know that I can use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`, but this method returns only files, that is on primary external memory, not on the mounted SD card (Secondary external storage).

I found that `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);` returns an element with index 1, for the secondary external storage, but this method gets files only for application sandbox (Android/data/packagename). So my question is how get path to secondary external path for public directory like DCIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, here is code snippet:

```
String strSDCardPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

if ((strSDCardPath == null) || (strSDCardPath.length() == 0)) {
    strSDCardPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE");
}

//If may get a full path that is not the right one, even if we don't have the SD Card there. 
//We just need the "/mnt/extSdCard/" i.e and check if it's writable
if(strSDCardPath != null) {
    if (strSDCardPath.contains(":")) {
        strSDCardPath = strSDCardPath.substring(0,strSDCardPath.indexOf(":"));
    }
    File externalFilePath = new File(strSDCardPath);

    if (externalFilePath.exists() && externalFilePath.canWrite()) {
        //do what you need here
    } 
}
```

For more details, read here: [Finding the SDCard Path on Android devices](http://pietromaggi.com/2014/10/19/finding-the-sdcard-path-on-android-devices/)

Comment: `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` returns `null` for me.

Comment: Read carefull my code snippet if `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` returns `null` check then `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE")`. I have tested this solutions on LG (LG G3, G2 Mini), Samsung (Note3, Galaxy S4, Galaxy S5) and HTC One and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
private boolean canWriteToFlash() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    return true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // Read only isn't good enough
    return false;
} else {
    return false;
} }
```

Comment: Yes this return only for *Primary Extarnal sd card*, but i want to path to public folders like DCIM, PICTURES MUSIC, for *secondary extarnal sd card*, If you have really sd card and put it in device.

Comment: String m_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);

Comment: for API level > 7 use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (DIRECTORY_PICTURES).

Answer (score 0):

For accessing multiple external storage, you could use the api

```
 ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(Context context);
 ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(Context context, String type);
```

This will return a path like `/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.example.foo/`, then you can replace `Android/data/com.example.foo/` with `DCIM` to get the path you want.

This method is not reliable, because the path `Android/data/com.example.foo/` will be different or changed in the future, but it worths to have a try.

You can see more information from the [official android documents](http://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html#multiple-external-storage-devices).